# Pushing an update to Google Play that will replace the existing app

Tags: android, google-play, publish

I have an app that is currently on the Play Store, and I would like to publish an update that will replace the existing app with another app that is an improved version of the old one. They were developed separately, so the two apps are way different, although they serve all the same purposes.

What needs to be the same in the new version and the old version for me to be able to publish is as an update instead of a brand new app?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The case you are describing sounds like a complete rewriting of the application. This is perfectly in line with the application update process of Google Play.

Google-play determines that an application is an update based on two criteria only:

- the package name of the app
- and its version code

To be considered as an update, your new app should have exactly the same package name as the former one ("`com.example.myapp`"), and its `android:versionCode`should be higher, in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file. Of course, your APK should be signed with your account's private key, like any application you publish under your account.

All the rest is up to you.

Comment: Except for the unique key.  If that doesn't match, you will not be able to replace the existing app.

Comment: Do you mean the RSA license key? This one is tied to your Play account, it is the same for all applications published under this account. I think, but I am not sure, that it appears under the applications settings and not under the account settings in the case this changes in the future. Anyway, using another key wouldn't prevent the application from being seen as an update, but it would lead the LVL check to fail (if used).

Comment: No I mean a "private key".  Any time I compile an app for distro, I need to compile it with that key, or Play will not accept it.  It basically proves that I am the author.  If I were to try to upload the exact same app without that key, it would be denied.  And that makes sense from a security standpoint.  It means someone can't just hijack my app without my knowledge.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean, sorry. This is the application package signature. You are perfectly right, an apk signed with a different signature would be rejected. I'll update my answer in a sec and +1 yours (even though I suggest rephrasing it).

Comment: I think this coversation serves to clarify.  And I'll +1 yours as well, because it contains information that mine does not.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful comments. As an alternative, what does convention say about updating the existing app that blocks usage and links to the new version on Play?

Comment: Not sure, I'm not aware of any guideline like this.

Comment: What if my existing application in Ionic and latest on is in React So play store will do update process same ?

Answer (score 1):

If they share the same unique key, you can overwrite the existing app with the new one.  It doesn't make any difference how much it's changed.  Play will automatically take care of notifying exising users of updates, and depending on their settings, update them automatically.

If your new version does NOT share the same unique key, you have no choice but to put up a new app.