# Updating existing users of entirely new re-wrote application on ios and android

Tags: android, ios

This is more of a feasibility question as I am new to mobile development.

Suppose there are already existing users using a version IOS and Android version of an application. However for some reasons, a total new application(re-wrote) is to be built to replace the existing one.

Is there any way we can update all the existing users with the new application without them having to re-download them?

Update:
I found an answer for android
[Pushing an update to Google Play that will replace the existing app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25083644/pushing-an-update-to-google-play-that-will-replace-the-existing-app)

But what about IOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your biggest feasibility challenge on iOS is Apple. From [the App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#functionality)

> 2.7 Apps that download code in any way or form will be rejected
>
> 2.8 Apps that install or launch other executable code will be rejected

So that makes it pretty unfeasible. They take this pretty seriously too: you'll probably lose your dev account, and certainly that app, if they notice you at it. So I would **very strongly recommend** you not attempt an in-place update, simply upload a new release to the App Store and let the user update according to their automatic or manual update settings.

If it's absolutely necessary that the application be updated immediately for continued functionality, the way developers typically handle a forcible update is to check their version on launch against the current version somewhere and pop up a modal that tells the user to go to the store app and update.